# ArrayList iterate inside jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, arraylist, autocomplete

I have passed arraylist from Servlet to JSP using session. I want to use autocomplete textbox with values from that arraylist. but i am not sure how to do that..

My list is

```
    <%! List l1=new ArrayList()%>
    <%l1=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("authorname");%>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = ['<%=l1.get(2)%>'];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
        <input id="tags">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

when i use specific values like "l1.get(2)" i can get that value in autocomplete textbox, but i am not sure how to give all values of list inside jquery..

Comment: Add an example of the value in the array.

Comment: I think you have a typo. You are missing opening of a script tag.

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan i can get the autocomplete of single element from list when i use l1.get(0), but i am not sure how to get all elements of the list in autocomplete...

Answer (score 1):

This is the snippet for loading the List to array type in javascript in JSP

```
<script>
  var availtags= [];
  <% for(String name:l1)
   {
  %>
     availtags.push("<%=name%>")
  <%
   }
  %>
</script>
```

> **EXPLANATION** after getting the attribute immediately use this script so that all the list value is been stored in the var availtags
>   and then use the same var for any reference in your javascript
>   function

Hope so this will be helpful for you

for more details

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)